# How to get selected place coordinates in google places autocomplete prediction in table view ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

i am able to get google places auto complete results in table view using below code.
now i am looking for how to get coordinate of selected place of tableview?

```
 func didAutocomplete(with predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {
    tableData.removeAll()

    for predicition in predictions
    {
         tableData.append(predicition.attributedFullText.string)
    }
    table1.reloadData()
}
```

Like if i select the row of table view then below method get invoked and i want to get coordinates of that particular place

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

Comment: try this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279252/convert-address-to-coordinates-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the GMSAutocompletePrediction, you will get a `placeID`, which is a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place. To get a place by ID, call `GMSPlacesClient lookUpPlaceID:callback:`, passing a place ID and a callback method.

So you need to declare another global array for saving placesID. Or you can use one array for saving a GMSAutocompletePrediction object; extract the attributedFullText in the cellForRowAtIndexPath for populating the labels and extract the placeID in didSelectRow.

Let say your tableData is an array of GMSAutocompletePrediction object.

```
var tableData = [GMSAutocompletePrediction]()
```

Then your didAutocomplete delegate method will be like this

```
func didAutocomplete(with predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {
    tableData = predictions
}
```

And your cellForRowAtIndexPath will be :-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    /* Intitialise cell */

    let predictionText = tableData[indexPath.row]attributedFullText.string
    print(“Populate \(predictionText) in your cell labels”)

    /* Return cell */
}
```

And your didSelectRowAt will be :-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let prediction = tableData[indexPath.row]

    if let placeID = predicition.placeID {
        let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
        placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(placeID) { (place, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let place = place else {
                print("No place details for \(placeID)")
                return
            }

            let searchedLatitude = place.coordinate.latitude
            let searchedLongitude = place.coordinate.longitude
        }
    }
}
```

You can explore more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/place-id)

Comment: Prediction object only returns 5 results. How can i get results more than 5?

Comment: have you implemented any GMSAutocompleteFilter() in the autocompleteQuery?

Comment: this predictions object is not accessible in func didSelectRowAt

Comment: its giving me error on 
if let placeID = prediction.placeID { .    
   Error : Value of type 'String' has no member 'placeID'

Comment: Because your tableData might still be an array of Strings. Read my answer fully.

Comment: thanks dear. its working. can you tell me how to get more than 5 results in prediction object. i did not put any filter

Comment: It's a limit by Google. I found the official link explaining among other the Autocomplete Services and JSON response. "predictions contains an array of places, with information about the place. The Places API returns up to 5 results. You can read about it here “https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete”. You need to check if you buy Enterprise Edition (Map Engine Pro) whether they are providing more than 5 results or not

Comment: can you help me in increasing results? I will give you payment for this.

Comment: Its beyond my ability dear :D. In fact its beyond the limit of any developer. You have to deal with google directly for this, because as I said in my previous comment, it is the limitation set by Google for some reasons. Even if you use GMSAutocompleteViewController directly, there also only 5 results are coming. You can use this link (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/support) for getting google support. As for the rewards part, an upvote and “mark as correct answer” would be much appreciated.

Comment: tapping the up arrow and tick mark near the top of my answer will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

In the last update of Google Maps you can simply get the address

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didSelect prediction: GMSAutocompletePrediction) -> Bool {
    let suggestedAddress = prediction.attributedFullText.string
    return true
}
```

In this delegate method you can get the full address.

Searched Address:
[image]

Output:
[image]

It will concatenate the upper and lower string of the searched address.