# Convert Multiple Addresses to Coordinates in Swift - IOS

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates, geocoding, street-address

I used this to be able to view one address at a time.
[Convert address to coordinates swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279252/convert-address-to-coordinates-swift)

However, I would like to view an array of addresses (131) and their respective coordinates

Here is my code:

```
func convertAddressToCoordinates() {
    for address in addresses {
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
            let placemark = placemarks?.first
            let lat = placemark?.location!.coordinate.latitude
            let lon = placemark?.location!.coordinate.longitude
            print("\(address): Lat: \(lat!), Lon: \(lon!)")
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it grabs the placemarks first coordinate; anyway to grab all placemarks?

Comment: Could you iterate over placemarks instead of just looking at the first one?